# Android One slow internet over time (Wifi)

Tags: wi-fi, internet, xiaomi, android-one

I own a Xiaomi Mi A3 with Android One.

My phone gets reaaaally slow internet connection every few months and stays that way until I factory reset it. It only happens on wifi, not on data. The wifi is fine, other devices connect to it perfectly. It happens across apps (youtube, browser, banking apps) and it's actually quite unusable.

It is clearly a software issue, since resetting the phone gets everything back and running smoothly again. It runs smooth for 3-4 months or so before I need to reset again.

This has happened a few times in the past, but I always solved it by Factory resetting it. However, that is pretty annoying since I have to set everything up from scratch (internet banking, etc).

Does anyone have any ideas about what I could do to solve that? Does anyone else have that problem?

Comment: What steps have you already tried other than performing a factory reset? Does it occur with every Wifi network?

Comment: It happens on other networks as well. I tried "resetting internet cache" or something like that. I can't remember exactly what the option said on settings. That didn't help at all.